# Not able to add Javascript in Community Builder

Tags: community

I am not able to add script tag in community builder as it is not supporting.Please let me know is there any way to add javascript in community builder.

Comment: try putting the javascript in the header section

Comment: I followed the above link but script tag is not supported and it will be disabled after locker service will be integrated.Is there any other way?

Comment: I have no documentation links on this but this sounds very reasonable from security stand point .If you can add a script tag then you might steal some info from the org ,provided hacker has access to the session Id .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use JavaScript on Experience Cloud pages, you need to place the JavaScript into the header of the page as noted in @Samir's answer.

However, inline scripts do not work without additional adjustments. By default [Lightening Locker blocks inline scripts for security](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_security_csp_overview.htm&type=5). You will need to either move your JavaScript into a Static Resource (recommended), or [reduce the Locker security level](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_security_csp_scriptlevel.htm&type=5) to "Relaxed CSP: Permit Access to Inline Scripts and Allowed Hosts".

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below link,this might help you solve your issue

[Adding javascript to community pages](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144691/adding-javascript-to-community-pages/144696)