# Handle "Not found" in community

Tags: community, napili

Is it possible handle "Not found" in community. For example when go to some not existing url community should redirect to some page responsible for handling 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript in "Head Markup" to this
In Community setting click on the Edit Head Markup button and add the markup

[Adding javascript to community pages](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144691/adding-javascript-to-community-pages)